# Jenkinsfile: Running docker.image(<myimagename>).inside in interactive mode

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

At present, when docker.image(...).inside is run within jenkinsfile, jenkins starts container in detach (daemon) mode.  Can someone please help me on how to make jenkins run container in interactive mode?

I tried giving "-it" options as in `docker.image(...).inside(-it)`, however I got below error:

> org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter unaryMinus java.lang.Object

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve by this?

Comment: I have a jmeter image built and stored in our private registry.  In the entrypoint.sh referred to within the dockerfile for jmeter image, I have provided "jmeter $@" to enable accepting jmeter args before running jmeter.

I would like to run this image in our jenkinsfile to performance test APIs. Hence, I am trying to use docker.image(jmeterImage).inside.  However, when the container runs it just comes out without running jmeter command as by default container is running in detach mode.  

I would like to run in interactive mode so that I can capture jmeter command results & use further.

Answer (score 2):

You shoudn't use Docker containers in interactive mode on your Jenkins. I don't know if that's even possible, but even if it is, it would block a build slot as long as it is waiting for user input. Instead, use an agentless input stage to ask for the parameters that you want to provide to the Docker container:

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  stage('Ask for input') {
    agent none
    steps {
      script {
        env.MY_PARAMETER = input ...
      }
    }
  }
  stage('Run JMeter') {
    agent { label 'docker' }
    steps {
      script {
        // Pass MY_PARAMETER into Docker container
        docker.image(...).inside("--env MY_PARAMETER ${env.MY_PARAMETER}") {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Since it's running in detach mode, how will I capture the jmeter test results to use it further down in my jenkinsfile?

I tried capturing the results by defining a var as in below:
``def results = docker.image(...).inside``.  However, results show up as null.

Comment: Assuming that jmeter prints everything to stdout, you can do something like def result = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'jmeter').

Comment: I have below stage snippet

``script {
                    docker.image('images/jmeter').inside {
                        echo 'Starting performance testing of configured APIs'
                        def results = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'jmeter')
                    }
                    echo "the results are: ${results}";
                }``

I have removed passing env vars for brevity here.
When I run this, I get script jmeter not found.

However, in my entrypoint.sh I have given below to run jmeter
jmeter $@

Comment: On a side note, if I don't run jmeter in interactive mode how can stdout be open and container would output to stdout?

Comment: Like this, it assumes that jmeter is in the path. Provide the full path to jmeter and it should work.

Comment: I see below only without results being output:

 Status: Downloaded newer image for images/jmeter:1.0.0
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
 $ docker run -t -d -u 0:0 -w /home/jenkins/workspace/ -v /home/jenkins/workspace/:/home/jenkins/workspace/:rw -v /home/jenkins/workspace/@tmp:/home/jenkins/workspace/@tmp:rw  --entrypoint cat images/jmeter:1.0.0
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
 Starting performance testing of configured APIs
[Pipeline] sh
 [] Running shell script
 + /jmeter/apache-jmeter-3.3/bin/jmeter.sh
[Pipeline] }
08:50:23 $ docker stop --time=1 8d
08:50:24 $ docker rm -f 8d